# I get a segmentation fault when I try to check for blank lines?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

So here is my code so far:

```
    char *c;
char inputString[200];

//get number of lines
c=fgets(inputString, 200, in_file);
while(c!=NULL){
    numLines++;
    c=fgets(inputString, 200, in_file);
}

rewind(in_file);

//array of instructions
char** instruc = malloc(numLines * 200); 

c = fgets(inputString, 200, in_file);

//fill the array of instructions.   
while (c != NULL){
    //allocate space for the string in the index of the array
    instruc[i] = malloc(200);
    strcpy(instruc[i], inputString);
    if (strcmp(instruc[i], "\n")==0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Blank line.\n");
        exit(-2);
    }
    i++;
    c = fgets(inputString, 200, in_file);
}
```

For some reason, my strcmp(instruc[i], "/n") is not catching a new line in my script, so whenever my code encounters a new line, I get a segmentation fault. Here is an example script I pass in:

```
CONST R1 11

PUSH R1
CONST R2 12
```

Between CONST R1 11 and PUSH R1, I get a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me with how to check for blanks between lines? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Empty(Blank) line is `"\n"` not `"/n"` for your program.

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems in your code.

```
char** instruc = malloc(numLines * 200);
```

This does not give you a dynamic 2-d character array , as you imagined.

Here is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of creating a dynamic string array..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW_SZ 5        //row size is number of strings
#define COL_SZ 200      //column size is number of characters in a string

int main()
{
int i;
char** str = malloc(ROW_SZ * sizeof(char*) );     //str is assigned char**

for ( i = 0; i < ROW_SZ; i++ )
    str[i] = malloc(COL_SZ * sizeof(char) );   //str[i] is assigned char*

// code here to use your dynamic 2-d string


for ( i = 0; i < ROW_SZ; i++ )
    free(str[i]);

free(str);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Blank line is compared with "\n" not with "/n".

Comment: I fixed that, but I still get a segfault.

Comment: Not getting any segfault, works fine for me. Could you debug using gdb. So that it would be easy enough to track where it is getting sefaulted.

Answer (score 0):

Logical error in This piece of Code

```
if (strcmp(instruc[i], "/n")==0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Blank line.\n");
        exit(-2);
    }
```

Here You are using "/n" instead of "\n" for checking blank line.

Comment: I fixed that, but I still get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char inputString[200];
    size_t i, numLines = 0;
    FILE *in_file = fopen("input.txt","r");

    while(NULL!=fgets(inputString, sizeof(inputString), in_file)){
        if (strcmp(inputString, "\n")==0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Blank line.\n");
            exit(-2);
        }
        ++numLines;
    }

    rewind(in_file);

    char** instruc = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char*)); 

    for(i=0;i<numLines;++i){
        instruc[i] = malloc(sizeof(inputString));
        fgets(instruc[i], sizeof(inputString), in_file);
    }
    fclose(in_file);
    //do something
    //deallocate memory
    return 0;
}
```